# Infragistics UltraWinGrid CTRL+A behaviour when using dropdown filters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a standard UltraWinGrid (V8.2) with some column/dropdown filters.

I have implemented <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all rows.

However when there is a filter applied, I only want to select all on the row that are not filtered out.

I choose my words carefully as there are a couple of Visible properties but they seem to pertain to actual visibility on the screen - obviously this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `UltraWinGrid.Rows.GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows()` or when doing your select operation use `UltraGridRow.IsFilteredOut`. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does Tom, thanks! I searched for things with Filter in the title but must have missed these. I've just used them and they work perfectly.

Comment: @IainMH - Infragistics is a beast of an API, I'm finding new things all the time! Glad to be of assistance :D